# Ruby on Rails controller order with strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, computer-science

So I'm trying to organize one of my views so that the articles of my website are listed by the name of the title. For example some of my articles are named "article pt.1, history pt.2, society pt.1, etc". I do have them sorted correctly using this line of code in the Articles controller

```
def index
    @articles = Article.order(:user_id)
end
```

It does work using the user id, but if I wanted to add another category and have them in alphabetical order, I would need to update the user id of each article which is not practical as they number a little over 200 in the database. What I would like to is somehow take a partial of the article title and sort each one like I am with the user_id field. This way I can sort each one using the string partial such as "article" from "article pt.1"

Thank you for reading and have a wonderful day!

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, would you mind elaborating a bit more?

Comment: @kajalojha He said it _Thank you for reading and have a wonderful day!_

Comment: Damn, ray got me good haha. I did post this when I was tired so I'm not surprised by this being unclear

Answer (score 0):

Why not just sort by the title? Assuming you have a column in your articles table called `title`:

For alphabetical order

```
def index
  @articles = Article.order(:title)
end
```

For reverse alphabetical order

```
def index
  @articles = Article.order(title: :desc)
end
```

If you really want to just sort by a substring of the title.  You'll have to add a new column to the articles table (called slug in this example):

`rails g migration AddSlugToArticles slug:text`

`rails db:migrate`

Then you'll have to update the slug field of every record

```
Article.all.each do |article|
  new_slug = #your code to generate substring here
  article.update(slug: my_string
end
```

then order by slug:

```
def index
  @articles = Article.order(:slug)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not very clear about the output that you want, but based on assumption and the description mentioned in the post, it seems like you want to sort the string field not based on whole value but based on substring.

It is better to use the order to get the strings alphabetically sorted.

```
@articles = Article.order(:title)
```

And it will also serve the purpose as it will first match the first alphabet of each string and also handle null values at the same time.

Why write a custom logic if the purpose is fulfilled by an already defined method.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it using the sort function instead of order using the :title field on the articles controller.

```
def index
  @articles = Article.sort(:title)
end
```